# Is there a module to generate glob patterns from date format strings in Perl?

Tags: perl, date, format

I want to generate glob patterns from date format strings, e.g.

```
%Y-%m-%d
```

should become

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
```

While

```
%C (e.g., Sat Nov 19 21:05:57 1994)
```

should become

```
[A-Z][a-z][a-z] [A-Z][a-z][a-z] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

I am wondering, if something like that already exists.

Comment: Since when could a date match "9999-99-99"?

Comment: there is a reason that Perl (and POSIX/Unix) have functions dedicated to parsing dates and times.  Use Time::Piece->strptime instead of glob.  A regex would be better than a glob, since glob's limitations would give you a very large string to match against.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/DateTime::Format::Strptime

Comment: @Zaid: I don't want to validate the date itself, but find files like "logfile.log.2011-07-26", while the way the date is appended can be configured through date format strings. Maybe I should have explained the szenario a bit more.

Comment: @MkV: Yeah you are right. I was a little bit stuck to the glob, because I am adapting existing code. But, yeah, I could just readdir and then match the files using a regex. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but helpful to achieve what you might want.

use the module from CPAN: Date::Parse.  It parses various date formats in different language.

From the docs:

`$lang = Date::Language->new('German');

$lang->str2time("25 Jun 1996 21:09:55 +0100");`

Document includes several different date formats that you can use.